# How do I add recaptcha to a custom form programatically?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using the following contrib module: https://www.drupal.org/project/google_recaptcha

How do I add a recaptcha to my form programatically, since the form I'm using isn't listed under forms on the config page of the module?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$form['recaptcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'recaptcha'
);
```

Comment: Not sure but you could try once . $form['captcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'captcha',
  '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA',
);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module doesn't implement `hook_element_info`, so it doesn't define a new element type. The code you're using looks like it's borrowed from the traditional captcha module, which does things a bit better and provides the element type.

Looking at the code, this is all you need in your form alter hook:

```
g_add_captcha($form, $form_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8, use the following (after installing the [reCaptcha module](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)):

```
$form['captcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'captcha',
  '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA',
);
```